# ViewBag missing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I give data to the ViewBag in the IAuthorizationFilter.OnAuthorization process, and it puts for the _Layout.cshtml-in, but when I use a partial view in normal view the data in the ViewBag is null.
This is normal behavior, or I am doing something wrong?

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    void IAuthorizationFilter.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

        filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.Name = this.name;
        filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.Menus = user.GetMenu(this.role);
    }
    ...
}
```

The _Layout.cshtml:

```
<section id="login">
    Hello, <span class="username">@ViewBag.Name</span>!
</section>
<nav>
     @Html.MenuLink(ViewBag.Menus as List<Entity.Models.MENU>, (string)ViewBag.Name)
</nav>
```

The view:

```
@model Web.ViewModels.RegistrationEntryViewModel

@Html.Partial("_RegistrationEntry", Model)
```

The action:

```
[MyAuthorize("ADMINISTRATORS")]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult NewRegistrationEntry()
{
    //The viewbag is already null here
    ...
}
```

Comment: It would be easier to understand the problem if there was some code illustrating it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please stop using `ViewBag` like that. It is not designed for this. And reason `ViewBag` is null in controller (I suspect) that these are different `ViewBag` objects in filter and in controller.

If you need to do repetitive actions in your view, there are better ways to do that. For your menu I would create an action that reads menu information, puts that in a `ViewModel` (not in a `ViewBag`) and outputs a partial view. Then in your Layout I'd render that partial action. (Also add some caching on this partial view)